# What is the proper interpretation of ἄνωθεν in Luke 1:3?

Tags: luke, word-study

### The Text

Luke 1:3 reads in the Greek (with the word in question highlighted; SBLGNT):

> ἔδοξε κἀμοὶ παρηκολουθηκότι **ἄνωθεν** πᾶσιν ἀκριβῶς καθεξῆς σοι γράψαι,
>   κράτιστε Θεόφιλε

It is translated a few different ways into English:

> KJV - It seemed good to me also, having had perfect understanding of all things **from the very first**, to write unto thee in order, most excellent Theophilus,
>
> ESV - it seemed good to me also, having followed all things
>   closely **for some time past**, to write an orderly account for you,
>   most excellent Theophilus,
>
> NASB - it seemed fitting for me as well, having investigated everything carefully **from the beginning**, to write it out for you in consecutive order, most excellent Theophilus;
>
> YLT -  it seemed good also to me, having followed **from the first** after all things exactly, to write to thee in order, most noble Theophilus,

### The Questions

There are two differing sets of questions related to ἄνωθεν.

**First, is ἄνωθεν best understood as a time reference or an authority reference?**

There is a minority view that may have been first proposed by [John Lightfoot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lightfoot) (1602-1675) that the word ἄνωθεν is a reference to "from above" (i.e. implied from God directly, Jesus directly, etc.; so an **authority reference**). Here is [a quote from Louis Berkhof's *Introduction to the New Testament*](http://books.google.com/books?id=t2tOGiaJzrUC&lpg=PT51&ots=ehBq5KLuak&dq=%22This%20interpretation%20is%20favored%20by%20the%20fact%20that%22&pg=PT51#v=onepage&q=%22This%20interpretation%20is%20favored%20by%20the%20fact%20that%22&f=false), (page 51? [basing that of google book link, as no number displayed on page itself]) that states this view:

> There are some Scripture passages that point to the inspiration of the gospel records. The older Lightfoot, (*Works* IV p. 1193 [incorrect? maybe [113 note e](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HQMUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q&f=false)], [114](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HQMUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false); [XII p. 7](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aohPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false), and following him Urquhart, *[The Bible its Structure and Purpose](https://archive.org/stream/bibleitsstructur01urqu#page/68/mode/2up)* I Ch. 5), find a proof for the inspiration of Luke's Gospel in 1:3, where they would translate the words παρηχολουθηχότι ἄνωθεν by "having had perfect understanding of all things *from above*." This interpretation is favored by the fact that ἄνωθεν has this meaning in [eight of the thirteen times](http://biblehub.com/thayers/509.htm) that it occurs in the New Testament, and in three of the remaining instances means *again*, while it is translated "from the beginning" only here and in Acts 26:4. The expressed purpose of Luke in writing his Gospel also falls in exceedingly well with the rendering *from above*. It is, he writes to Theophilus, that you may have the *certainty* of those things in which you have been instructed. Yet the verb παρηχολουθέω, meaning, *to follow up carefully*, and thus, *to obtain knowledge*, argues decisively against it.

The majority opinion has it as a **time reference**, as the ESV and NASB more directly translate (notice that the KJV and YLT are more vague in how they could be taken).

***In answering this first question, please give arguments for and against both views, rather than just whichever view you conclude is correct.***

**Second,** based on the answer to the first, then...

**(1) If interpreted as an authority reference, would "from above" be more specifically God the Father, the Son, an angel, or what?**

To clarify (1), who or what is more directly referred to by the oblique reference "from above"?

**(2) If interpreted as a time reference, is ἄνωθεν meaning**

- **(a) "for some time past" (ESV), where the implication is his investigation has been going on for some time,**
- **(b) "from the beginning" (NASB), where the time reference is to the period his investigative work covered, or**
- **(c) "from the first" (YLT), where the translation in context appears to refer to the period over which he was doing his investigating (i.e. investigating from the beginning)?**

To clarify (2), is the intent for Luke to say sometime long after the events, he researched the things and had been doing so for a while now, so (a); or that in the research, he had covered from Jesus' birth onward, so (b), which seems to be the typical interpretation; or rather that he is actually identifying himself as part of the "eyewitness" group ([Luke 1:1-3, YLT](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%201%3A1-3&version=YLT)) that has previously born written testimony, whom he is about to join his written testimony to, having been following the matter *ever since Christ's birth*(!), as (c) might imply?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than spend a month or two answering all of the questions laid out ἄνωθεν (wink), I'll add yet another perspective that neither authority nor time seem to be the dominant categories according to [LSJ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%E1%BC%84%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%BD), but instead:

1. spatial position (as when the "veil of the shrine was split from above unto below" in Mt 27:51), which may include heaven above earth, and then therefore
2. narrative position, as I used it in my first sentence above.

Since Luke refers to many a narrative (διήγησις) he may simply be saying he is collecting, ordering, and harmonizing "the above", hence his intent "to write precisely successively" (ἀκριβῶς καθεξῆς).

Comment: +1 for conceivably valid option. My "authority" reference from Lightfoot I believe takes it in the #1 sense, but with a figurative meaning (i.e. "from above" is a spatial position reference figuratively saying "from God who is above in heaven," i.e. God directly). The #2 sense seems to fit both a "time" reference as well as your proposal as I read [the entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da%29%2Fnwqen). I cannot accept this answer, however, without far more argumentation as to why it should be taken this way as opposed to the other ways.