# Why do Matthew & Luke report that Joseph (Jesus' stepfather) had two different fathers?

Tags: matthew, luke, contradiction, source-criticism, synoptic-problem

I ran into a YouTube video that claims the Gospels of Luke and Mathew contradict on the name of Joseph's father. Luke claims that Joseph's father was a man named **Heli** but Mathew claims that the father of Joseph was a man named **Jacob**.
Evidence from the Bible

*Luke 3:23*

> Jesus, when he began his ministry, was about thirty years of age, being the son (as was supposed) of Joseph, the son of Heli.

*Mathew 1:16*

> and Jacob the father of Joseph the husband of Mary, of whom Jesus was born, who is called Christ.

How did this contradiction come about? What does this imply regarding Matthew's knowledge of Luke's work or Luke's knowledge of Matthew's?

Comment: As originally written, this question was likely to be closed as a duplicate. However, you also asked *how did this contradiction come about?* This is a question of source criticism relevant to the Synoptic Problem. I have expanded the question to focus on this so that your question is less likely to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The genealogies**

There have been many explanations proposed to answer the contradiction. The 2 most popular are:

1. Matthew gives Joseph's genealogy and Luke gives Mary's (the inverse is sometimes proposed as well)
2. Jacob & Heli were half-brothers (same mother). Joseph's physical father was Jacob, who married Heli's wife after Heli died (Levirate marriage), making Joseph the son of Heli according to the Law of Moses. This theory comes from the work of early historian Julius Africanus, see further discussion [here](https://www.christalmighty.net/2021/10/genealogies.html?m=1).

**The Synoptic Problem**

Some see the difference in genealogies as evidence that Luke did not know Matthew's Gospel, and solve the Synoptic Problem in such a way that these 2 documents are literarily independent.

I disagree. Many hold that Matthew was not the first Gospel written. I respectfully hold a different view. My study of the Synoptic Problem has led me to the conclusion that both Mark and Luke were dependent upon Matthew. For a much more extended argument (if that's of interest), see my work on Matthean Priority [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGACqQS4ut5i8CVQcNzf4pBIA8hC-AIpN)  (Matthean Priority = Matthew was first).

I recognize that most scholars believe in Markan Priority; I also recognize why they do so. For a brief discussion, see [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/54190/39862) under the heading *It’s the majority view among New Testament scholars: this is unremarkable given the history of the Synoptic Problem*.

But this also creates a conundrum. If Luke used Matthew as a source--and I firmly conclude he did--why are the genealogies different?

As demonstrated on this site and many others, a definite answer on the differing genealogies is not universally acknowledged. But if Luke knew Matthew's Gospel and used a different genealogy anyway, that means one of two things:

- Luke thought Matthew was wrong (unlikely since he quoted hundreds of verses from Matthew)
- Luke had access to a different family line

I find the most parsimonious solution to be that Luke - who has just provided an extensive account from Mary's perspective -  is providing Mary's genealogy (therefore using a different family line).

Comment: Was this person Luke, a member of Jesus twelve? Because it's been proven that he accompanied Peter and learned from him

Comment: Isn't the obvious question: why didn't the author of Luke specifically say it's Mary's genealogy he's relaying?

Comment: I'd add the possibility that they are simply two names used by the same person. There are other examples in the NT of a person having both a Hebrew name and a Greek name. (Saul and Paul, Simon and Cephas/Peter, etc. Perhaps Heli is short for [Heliodorus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktB_b9G5IOo)

Comment: @DongLi per Luke 1:2-3 it appears Luke was not himself an eyewitness of the ministry of Jesus, but that he received his information from those who were. Luke did travel with Paul on multiple occasions.

Comment: @AviAvraham a number of answers have been proposed to this question, but we do not know. A common view is that Luke wanted to list only male names in the genealogy. Some see in Luke 3:23 a hint that he's not actually providing Joseph's genealogy. Also, in Greek Luke doesn't explicitly say Joseph was the "son" of Heli, just "of Heli", which is the Greek he uses for tracing generations through most of the genealogy.

Comment: Then where did Luke learn that Heli was the father of Jesus because the Bible is known to focus on the male roots and not on the female roots

Comment: @DongLi I think it likely that Luke interviewed Mary - see my thoughts in [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/91495/39862)

Comment: It could be that he interviewed Mary . Luke should have provided a background because he was not a first person witness to Jesus life and ministry

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

There is no contradiction because these are partly **two different** genealogies.

**Explanation**

Luke gives the list right from Adam and Matthew gives the list from Abraham.

The list is the same from Abraham to David in both Matthew and Luke.

However, the genealogies move away in **two different** directions from David onwards.

> “These are the names of those born to him (King David) in Jerusalem:
> Shammua, and Shobab, and **Nathan, and Solomon**” (2 Sam 5:14).

Matthew continues the list from King David through King Solomon (Matthew 1:6) while Luke does so through Nathan (Luke 3:31)

So, Jacob and Heli cannot be half-brothers.

Multiple names of Heli/Jacob for the same person also cannot solve the issue because, as is clear, these are two different genealogies; one from King Solomon and the other from Nathan.

**Comparison of the Two**

One thing is sure:

Jacob is the **biological** father of Joseph, the husband of Mary:

> “Jacob then **begat (Greek – egenneisan = procreated)** the Joseph the
> husband of Mary” (biblehub).

This is according to Matthew.

Luke simply says:

> “Joseph **of** the Heli **of** the Maththat” etc (Luke 3:23-24).

Now, Joseph can be **of** Heli in different ways:

1. Could be a biological son;
2. Could be an adopted son;
3. Could be a son-in-law; etc.

**Conclusion**

So, it is clear that Matthew gives the biological genealogy of Joseph through King Solomon.

Luke gives the genealogy of Joseph through his marital alliance with Mary’s family.

Since these are two different genealogies from David through Solomon and Nathan, there is no room for any contradiction.

Comment: I do not understand you, both move in the same direction towards Jesus. I just truncated to the grand father bit.

Comment: I'm not saying Julius Africanus' theory is correct, but the half-brother theory is based on the premise that they had the same mother and different fathers...so it's possible (though not certain) that Jacob's father was a descendant of Solomon and Heli's father was a descendant of Nathan. But I do think the person_name of person_name of person_name of in Greek leaves open the possibility you've mentioned, +1.

Comment: @DongLi – Both moved in different directions until Joseph steps in. He is biological son of Jacob and became “of Heli” through either adoption or marriage alliance.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod – Appreciate your up-vote. I am sure you are aware of the curse on Jehoiachin (Jeconiah/Coniah) in Jer 22:30. None of his seed will sit on David’s throne. So Joseph is disqualified as king through him. But Joseph, through (adoption/son-in-law) Heli, is eligible to be a king.

Answer (score 0):

The other plausible reason that explains the difference is that Biblical entities are known to have multiple names like **Jacob** who was also called **Israel**, **Peter** is also known as **Simon** and so it follows that Joseph's father had two names **Jacob** and **Heli**